# Is this graph well known?

Tags: graph-theory

The vertices of G are the k-subsets of some set of size n. Two k-subsets are connected by an edge of G if their symmetric difference is of size 2. The integers n and k are chosen so that the graph is not trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the Johnson graph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph

Comment: Thank you for info. 
Is it known if those graphs are Hamiltonian?

Comment: Yes, they are. The key word is combinatorial gray codes, see for example section 4 in www4.ncsu.edu/~savage/AVAILABLE_FOR_MAILING/survey.ps